# Microsoft Teams improperly prompting to install app for personal use

Tags: microsoft-teams

### Description

In a chat with our bot, Microsoft Teams is displaying a prompt to install the app for "personal use". However, our app does not have the `"personal"` scope in the manifest; only the `"team"` scope is set.

Furthermore, when you click the "Add app" button a modal displays to add the app, yet nothing gets installed, the modal closes, and the prompt remains. Clicking the "X" clears the prompt, yet it returns when you come back to the chat. This creates confusion and poor user-experience.

Relevant part of our manifest:

```json
{
  "bots": [
    {
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Expected Behavior

The install for personal use prompt should not display when the app does not have the `"personal"` scope.

### Screenshots

[image: personal use prompt]

### Manifest

Here's a manifest.json with some redactions

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "id": "[REDACTED]",
  "packageName": "com.package.name",
  "name": {
    "short": "[REDACTED]",
    "full": ""
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "[REDACTED]",
    "mpnId": "",
    "websiteUrl": "[REDACTED]",
    "privacyUrl": "[REDACTED]",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "[REDACTED]"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "[REDACTED]",
    "full": "[REDACTED]"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#430097",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "[REDACTED]",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": false,
      "supportsVideo": false,
      "supportsFiles": false
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [],
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "orgWide": [],
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "ChannelMessage.Read.Group",
          "type": "Application"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If possible, could you please share the manifest Json, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: We are trying the same but if we add teams scope it directly shows Add to Team button.
![Screenshot 2023-08-01 132251](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/assets/93527375/4967607b-8a5a-4499-8258-025775991627)

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I've updated the description with our full manifest.json. The screenshot you provided is similar to what we say. However, you should only see the "Add to a team" button, without the dropdown to add at a different scope.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, we will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: We are able to reproduce the issue. We are checking with the engineering team to determine if it is a bug or Bydefault behavior, and we will let you know once we have an update.

Comment: We have raised bug for the same . We will inform you once we get any update.