# Microsoft Teams Task Module in Bot Chat Improperly Displays Install Modal

Tags: microsoft-teams

### Description

Opening a Task Module in a Bot Chat displays an "install/add" app modal instead of the intended Task Module. If you click the "Add" button on the app modal, the modal closes, and the correct Task Module renders.

We have no idea what clicking "Add" does. This same install/add modal displays with every attempt to open the Task Module.

This is a tremendous degradation in user experience and app functionality.

### Expected Behavior

The intended Task Module should render when clicking the "Open" button.

### Screenshots

This is an Adaptive Card message in a Chat with our Bot. The "Open" button returns a Task Module.

[image: task module open button]

When the user clicks "Open" this modal shows up with an "Add" button. Clicking the "X" closes the modal and shows an error message in the chat. It doesn't open the intended Task Module. However, clicking "Add" closes the modal and **does** render the intended Task Module.

[image: task module install modal]

### Manifest

Here's our manifest.json with some redactions

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "id": "[REDACTED]",
  "packageName": "com.package.name",
  "name": {
    "short": "[REDACTED]",
    "full": ""
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "[REDACTED]",
    "mpnId": "",
    "websiteUrl": "[REDACTED]",
    "privacyUrl": "[REDACTED]",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "[REDACTED]"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "[REDACTED]",
    "full": "[REDACTED]"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#430097",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "[REDACTED]",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": false,
      "supportsVideo": false,
      "supportsFiles": false
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [],
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "orgWide": [],
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "ChannelMessage.Read.Group",
          "type": "Application"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Task Module Snippet

```json
{
  "task": {
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
      "title": "Test Module",
      "height": "medium",
      "width": "medium",
      "card": {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "version": "1.4",
          "body": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Hello, world!"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Notes

This issue only seems to happen in Chats. If we post the same message to a Channel the Task Modules work as expected.

Furthermore, note that we are only using the "team" scope, not the "personal" scope in our manifest.

Lastly, this issue only presents on desktop (PC and Mac) and in the web browser. The mobile client works as expected.

Comment: We checked this at our end by running the sample - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/csharp. We have removed personal and groupchat from bot scopes. We do not see add option at all, we could only see Add to a team and Add to a meeting options - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sk0E.png

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I don't understand what you're saying. Did the Task Module in Chat with your Bot open as expected? Or did it prompt with an installation modal that you provided a screenshot of. I would suggest using our manifest and not the one provided in the sample because ours has different permissions and scopes.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have a hunch this has to do with not having the "personal" scope. It's similar to the other issue I posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76790430/microsoft-teams-improperly-prompting-to-install-app-for-personal-use).

When I add the personal scope this issue goes away.

Comment: We are checking this internally, we will get back to you with an update.

Comment: Could you please let us know how you are opening the bot in personal scope when the manifest has only "team" scope mentioned. We checked again and since the bot has team scope only there is no way for us to access the bot in personal scope. Would it be possible for yoou to share deployed manifest so that we can check it at our end as well?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, our bot uses the "Send to conversation" endpoint of the Bot Framework REST API to send a message to the user. This opens a chat between the user and our bot in which we're able to send them a message like what you see in the screenshots. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference). Do you have a secure method for me to send our manifest?

Comment: Please share your manifest at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, done. The subject of the email is the same as the title of this post.

Comment: We have received your mail, we will check and get back to you.

Comment: We uploaded your app in demo tenant, we see only add to a team/meeting - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hvuw.png. You mentioned this issue only happens in Chats. But how are you accessing this bot in the chat when personal scope is removed from bot scopes. It could be possible that you might have installed same bot in personal scope earlier and it might cause this issue. Please uninstall the bot from personal scope and try again if your app is not intended for personal scope.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT we see your installation. There was message sent to the General channel with a "Settings" button. If you click that button, our bot will send you a settings card in Chat. Click the last button in the settings card to open a task module.

Comment: Issue is happening because you are using the bot in personal scope, but it is not mentioned in manifest scope. That is the reason, when the personal scope is added this issue goes away. Please add personal scope in manifest and install the bot in personal scope if bot is used in personal scope as well.